# Error when trying to use Binance api Client

Tags: python, binance-api-client, python-binance

I am located in California and I am trying to use the Binance API.  When using this code:

```
from binance.client import Client`

client = Client(api`*`key, secret_key)
```

this code produces the error:

```
raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=0): Service unavailable from a restricted location according to 'b. Eligibility' in https://www.binance.com/en/terms. Please contact customer service if you believe you received this message in error.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is intended functionality of Binance geofencing.
Since you are from United States, you are in a restricted location. From https://www.binance.com/en/terms part b. Eligibility:

> For the purposes hereof, “Restricted Location” shall include the
> United States, Malaysia, Ontario (Canada), ...